# Power savings box power factor

Tags: power

I came across an on-line ad claiming to save "90%" or even 100% on my electricity bill. Wow! And "power companies hate this trick"!

[image]

I gathered some courage, clicked through the ad, and this is sort of how it's explained:

> Appliances always draw more power than they need to run due to inefficiencies and noise on the sine wave. Voltex reduces this noise therefor decreases the amount of electricity wasted. It does not change what the meter reads or steal extra power from anywhere, it just uses the energy more efficiently therefor needing less of it. Voltex is your power company's worst nightmare. They have been trying to hide Voltex from the everyday consumer and have even banned it in retail shops.

An accompanying figure in the sales material appears to show a power factor correction and noise reduction:

[image]

And the plug-in device is nothing like a DC magnet as shown in the ad. Here's the touted "Voltex Power Saver":

[image]

(If you really must read it all, it's [here](https://getvoltex.com/article4) )

Now, all hype and scam aside, and purely from an EE perspective, what exactly is a "Power Saver" that "cleans up" the noisy sinusoid of your household power, which then somehow translates to savings on the electrical bill?

Is this merely an (adaptive) **power factor correction**, or is it something else?

Most utility companies do not apply surcharges for minor PF deviations, so the savings -if any- can't really be that high.

Note also the other claimed function: **noise reduction**. Are real or reactive power savings to be had by filtering a noisy supply? And if so, how is this quantified?

I can imagine that power delivered outside a narrow band around 50H or 60Hz may be wasted. Perhaps a minuscule amount is even billed for but not effectively used, but is this even a real problem?

Another possibility is that the device is just a fixed shunting capacitor to improve a guessed power factor. And that the noise clean-up is a side effect of shunting, with no benefit other than that it provides an air of scientific sophistication in sales copy.

Your thoughts?

Comment: From their own mouths, "*It does not change what the meter reads ...*" That's all you need to know. "*Voltex is your power company's worst nightmare.*" Anything that improved power factor would be a delight to a power company.

Comment: It's a scam. Don't try to make any sense of it.

Comment: Where I live, residential areas usually don't care about reactive power being monitored (except private houses, special contracts with 3-phase, etc), so it's useless to have such a thing, plus no aparatus will reduce the active power consumed.

Comment: It is a capacitor. So it reduces the current a bit by increasing power factor and perhaps filters harmonic distortion a bit. Both will reduce the apparent power, but not your bill since you are only billed for real power. Power companies don't like it because some people think they are being cheated by the power company when they don't see any change in their power bill.

Comment: @CharlesCowie, brilliant: "Power companies don't like it because..." Now there's the support for their claim; and some solid irony.

Comment: Of course, slapping a capacitor on there doesn't help unless you have an inductive overall load. Which you *probably* do, but you might have a capacitive load, and in that case one of these things would make it worse!

Comment: There is only one way that device could reduce your power bill to zero. If it starts a fire and burns your house to the ground. Then, no house, no power and no power bill. And, by the way, I am mentioning house fire because when you plug in fraudulent junky stuff, there is always the chance that it will start a fire.

Answer (score 8):

Fraudulent claims capture inquisitive minds. This technique is only used by large industrial factories that pay for motor reactive power. It never works for consumers. But it may reduce fan motor click noises when switched off if you have any such electronic effects. It’s just a 1nF metal film cap costing << $1 that one might be put across a motor switch to reduce EMI.

The “after” plot and all “claims” are fraudulent in practice.

Comment: Tony, what are fan motor click noises?

Comment: Dry switching AC motor inductance arcs

Comment: Did you really buy it and took a look inside? Share it.

Comment: don't need to, don't want to. I understand it